# Error: The requested resource could not be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to implement mailchimp v3. And for that this is the code I am using to get this work. But I don't know what is `/lists/id/members` and from where I can get that. And thus I am getting this error

```
Error: The requested resource could not be found.
       at Request._callback (/mailchimp-api-v3/index.js:515:30)
```

Here is my code

```
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3')
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX');

mailchimp.post('/lists/id/members', {
  email_address : 'myEmailId',
  status : 'subscribed'
})
.then(function(results) {
  console.log({results})
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log({err})
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the `/(id)/` part with your actual list id, following this official guide.

https://mailchimp.com/help/find-audience-id/

Comment: Cool!!! Thanks... Now I can see the `results` in the logs. But didn't get any email. Could you please let me know how can I send an email containing some text...

Comment: Mailchimp send emails in `campaigns`, you might want to read more in https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-campaigns/ and
https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/

Comment: Hi I think mailchimp does not send email. I have to use maildrill for that. Isn't it?

Comment: It does send emails, but it sends them according to predefined campaigns, probably not what you were looking for.